# Change icon after click (others icons not change)

Tags: jquery, toggleclass

I need after click with jQuery change icon from plus to minus with toggle class
now I have problem that after clicked all "span" changed icon.

```js
// FAQ
$('#content-in > article > div > ul > li > p').hide();
$('#content-in > article > div > ul > li > h3').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // skrýt všechny spany
  var $this = $(this).parent().find('p');
  $('#content-in > article > div > ul > li > p').not($this).hide();
  // rozjetí textu
  $this.toggle("fast", "swing");

  // obarvení pozadí + další změny po kliknutí a rozjetí (u ostatních elementů se tato vlastnost neaplikuje)
  var tittle = $("#content-in > article > div > ul > li > h3");
  $(tittle).toggleClass('activeLol');
  $(tittle).not(this).removeClass('activeLol');

  var $plus_minus = $('#content-in > article > div > ul > li > h3 > span');
  $plus_minus.toggleClass('fa-minus').toggleClass('fa-plus');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="Accordion mt30">
  <li class="Accordion-item">
    <h3 class="Accordion-item-title" style="text-align: left;"><span class="fa fa-plus"> </span>1. Pokud je vybrané zboží momentálně ve statusu objednáno u dodavatele či vyprodáno, co to znamená ?</h3>
    <p class="Accordion-item-content" style="display: none;">Zboží, které je momentálně ve statusu objednáno u dodavatele, bohužel není k dispozici. Produkty jsou objednány u našeho italského dodavatele s tím, že čekáme na jejich výrobu a následnou dopravu do České republiky. Dodací lhůta je však různě odlišná,
      zpravidla 2-3 týdny (v některých případech může být delší).</p>
    <p class="Accordion-item-content" style="display: none;">Zboží, které je momentálně ve statusu vyprodáno, je bohužel dlouhodobě nedostupné s tím, že jeho naskladnění zatím nemáme potvrzeno.</p>
  </li>
  <li class="Accordion-item">
    <h3 class="Accordion-item-title"><span class="fa fa-plus"> </span>2. Pokud si objednám zboží, které je momentálně skladem, jaká je dodací lhůta ?</h3>
    <p class="Accordion-item-content" style="display: none;">Při objednání produktů, které jsou na našich webových stránkách „Skladem“ je dodací lhůta zpravidla dva až čtyři pracovní dny.</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you're selecting all the `h3 span` elements. Instead you can use DOM traversal to find the one related to the clicked `h3` by using the `this` keyword within the click event handler. Try this:

```
var $plus_minus = $(this).find('span').toggleClass('fa-minus fa-plus');
$('h3 span').not($plus_minus).removeClass('fa-minus').addClass('fa-plus');
```

Comment: But after clicked other elements so stay minus insteand of plus (to back on inactive element).

Answer (score 1):

Get the relative icon to the clicked element

```
$('#content-in > article > div > ul > li > h3').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
$('h3 span').not($(this).find('span')).removeClass('fa-minus').addClass('fa-plus');//change all classes to fa-plus
$(this).find('span').toggleClass('fa-minus fa-plus');//change the current one 
});
```

```js
// FAQ
$('ul > li > p').hide();
$(' ul > li > h3').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // skrýt všechny spany
  var $this = $(this).parent().find('p');
  $('ul > li > p').not($this).hide();
  // rozjetí textu
  $this.toggle("fast", "swing");

  // obarvení pozadí + další změny po kliknutí a rozjetí (u ostatních elementů se tato vlastnost neaplikuje)
  var tittle = $(" ul > li > h3");
  $(tittle).toggleClass('activeLol');
  $(tittle).not(this).removeClass('activeLol');

  var $plus_minus = $(' ul > li > h3 > span');
  $('h3 span').not($(this).find('span')).removeClass('fa-minus').addClass('fa-plus'); //change all classes to fa-plus
  $(this).find('span').toggleClass('fa-minus fa-plus'); //change the current one 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<ul class="Accordion mt30">
  <li class="Accordion-item">
    <h3 class="Accordion-item-title" style="text-align: left;"><span class="fa fa-plus"> </span>1. Pokud je vybrané zboží momentálně ve statusu objednáno u dodavatele či vyprodáno, co to znamená ?</h3>
    <p class="Accordion-item-content" style="display: none;">Zboží, které je momentálně ve statusu objednáno u dodavatele, bohužel není k dispozici. Produkty jsou objednány u našeho italského dodavatele s tím, že čekáme na jejich výrobu a následnou dopravu do České republiky. Dodací lhůta je však různě odlišná,
      zpravidla 2-3 týdny (v některých případech může být delší).</p>
    <p class="Accordion-item-content" style="display: none;">Zboží, které je momentálně ve statusu vyprodáno, je bohužel dlouhodobě nedostupné s tím, že jeho naskladnění zatím nemáme potvrzeno.</p>
  </li>
  <li class="Accordion-item">
    <h3 class="Accordion-item-title"><span class="fa fa-plus"> </span>2. Pokud si objednám zboží, které je momentálně skladem, jaká je dodací lhůta ?</h3>
    <p class="Accordion-item-content" style="display: none;">Při objednání produktů, které jsou na našich webových stránkách „Skladem“ je dodací lhůta zpravidla dva až čtyři pracovní dny.</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: lol good one i just simplified you function man :)) copy only the content of the event to your event

Comment: see my snippet above